# Want to make my zipcode text field required while adding the products in the shopping cart

Tags: magento-1.9, product, addtocart, zipcode

I am making the magento ecommerce website. I want to make the zipcode text field on product page required (compulsory to proceed the next page) before users add the products in shopping cart. I want to make compulsory for every users to check the zipcode for their area before adding the products in the shopping cart.

This is my cod.phtml code:

```
<?php
/***************************************
 *** Cash On Delivery ***
 ***************************************
 *
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2015
 * @company     NetAttingo Technologies
 * @package     Netgo_Cod
 * @author      NetGo
 * @dev         netattingomails@gmail.com
 *
 */

$msgData = Mage::helper('netgo_cod')->getConfigData(); 
if($msgData['zip_status'] == 1){
?>
<div class="input-box">
    <div class="z-btn">
        <label>Zip Code : </label><input type="text" placeholder="Enter your pincode" value="" name="cod" class="product-custom-option" id="cod" size="29" style='color:black; font-size:12px' required>
        <button type="button" onclick="checkCOD();" name="zip-check" title="Check" class="button" id="zip-check"><span><span>Check</span></span></button>
    </div>
    <div id="cod_msg"></div>
</div>

<script>
    function checkCOD(){
        var cod = $('cod').value;
        if(cod == ''){
            $('cod_msg').update('<span class="cod-error"><?php echo $msgData['emp_msg']; ?></span>');
            return
        }else{
            $('cod_msg').update('<img src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl( Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB, true ).'media/cod/img/ajax-loader-2.gif';?>">'); 
            new Ajax.Request('<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl().'netgo/cod/check';?>', {
                method:'post',
                parameters: {zipcode: cod}, 
                onSuccess: function(transport) {
                    var response = transport.responseText || "no response text";
                    $('cod_msg').update(response);
                },
                onFailure: function() { alert('Something went wrong...'); }
            });
        }
    }
</script>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Any answer stackys

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, onclick of **Pincode Check** button, add an extra class to the form `suppose: checked`. Then check that form contains `checked` class or not onclick of **Add to Cart** button. Hope this script will easy to implement.

Comment: Can you please suggest me in the code i provided i did not got you